# Add custom search engines on Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, search

One of the most powerful productivity tools I use on Chrome is [custom search engines](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-custom-search-engines-in-chrome-for-more-efficient-searching/). However, I was wondering how I can do the same thing on Chrome for Android?

I went through the settings on Chrome for Android, but understandably it doesn't have that feature. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the sources, the option is reported by a few users for it. And hope so it would be released in future updates.

As of now, it is not possible to change the default search engine in Android.

Comment: do you have a reference?

Comment: its open in google forums asked similar to you by fans of chrome